# Breadcrumb returning url with % within url structure

Tags: php, url, structure

I'm working on a Nitrosell website - first time and when I click on product category 
e.g. http://www.examaple.com/category/product-type it shows this as the url.

When i click on the breadcrumb within the product page it would return http://www.example.com/category/product%20type

Any help appreciated in how I can keep the url as the original.

Cheers

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: all i have access to is this
{ifThereAre breadcrumbs}
  <div class="breadcrumbs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="{home['url']}" rel="nofollow">Home</a></li>
      {foreach breadcrumb}
        {if ((breadcrumb['url']))}
          <li>
          &raquo; <a href="{breadcrumb['url']}" rel="nofollow">{breadcrumb['name']}</a>
          </li>
        {else}
          {* If the breadcrumb doesn't have a URL, don't output a link *}
          <li>
          &raquo; <strong>{breadcrumb['name']}</strong>
          </li>
        {endIf}
      {endForEach}

Comment: Is this not helpful?